# Problem with validation of Angular form after too much deletion of fields

Tags: html, angular, forms, angular-forms

So I have a component in which I add dynamically drivers.
And the user can choose to add as much drivers as he/she pleases. 
The problem is when too much was added, and the user deletes some drivers.

The form does not forget all the fields it would seem even if those inputs were taken out. That is the driver object was removed from the array. The form remains invalid, because the next button remains disabled.
I stripped down the code as much as I could, this was the approach I went with.

```html
<button type="button" (click)="addDriver()">
        Add driver
</button>

<form #form="ngForm" class="topMargin">
    
        <div *ngFor="let driver of drivers; let driverIndex = index">
            <div class="header field-desc" >
                <div class="field-title title">
                    Tittle......
                </div>
                <div class="actions">
                    <button class="btn btn-secondary error"
                            (click)="deleteDriver( driver, driverIndex ); $event.stopPropagation()"
                            *ngIf="drivers.length > 1 && !driver.driverIsContractor">
                        <span class="pic-icon pic-delete"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                     <input type="text"  id="driverSurname{{driverIndex}}"                 
                     name="driverSurname{{driverIndex}}" [(ngModel)]="driver.name" required>
                    ...... input fields 
            </div>
        </div>
</form>
```

Comment: What is your question? Also I would strongly recommend you create an [mcve] using https://stackblitz.com and then share that link in your question.

Comment: A ups, well the problem is those inputs seem to stay in the form. I need to refresh somehow the form. Or do a different approach. Because I cant validate the drivers like this .

Comment: Yes, this type of problem really needs a stackblitz. Can you put a simple example together? Just one form with a few fields and its associated component? (If you just modify the `app.component.ts` and `app.component.html` in the default stackblitz, you don't have to add much else.)

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using reactive forms instead of template-driven forms. Reactive forms is set up to handle multiple dynamic fields.

I have a complete working example here: https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular-ReactiveForms/tree/master/Demo-Final

For example, here is one I did for multiple addresses:

```
    <div formArrayName="addresses"
         *ngFor="let address of addresses.controls; let i=index">

      <div [formGroupName]="i">
        <div class="form-group row mb-2">
          <label class="col-md-2 col-form-label"
                 attr.for="{{'street1Id' + i}}">Street Address 1</label>
          <div class="col-md-8">
            <input class="form-control"
                   id="{{'street1Id' + i}}"
                   type="text"
                   placeholder="Street address (required)"
                   formControlName="street1"
                   [ngClass]="{'is-invalid': (address.controls.street1.touched || 
                                              address.controls.street1.dirty) && 
                                              !address.controls.street1.valid }">
            <span class="invalid-feedback">
              <span *ngIf="address.controls.street1.errors?.required">
                Please enter your street address.
              </span>
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row mb-2">
          <label class="col-md-2 col-form-label"
                 attr.for="{{'street2Id' + i}}">Street Address 2</label>
          <div class="col-md-8">
            <input class="form-control"
                   id="{{'street2Id' + i}}"
                   type="text"
                   placeholder="Street address (second line)"
                   formControlName="street2">
          </div>
        </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row mb-2">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-primary"
                type="button"
                [title]="addresses.valid ? 'Add another mailing address' : 'Disabled until the existing address data is valid'"
                [disabled]="!addresses.valid"
                (click)="addAddress()">
          Add Another Address
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I'll probably try to re write it in reactive forms, so I can change the formGroup and manage it like that. I actually tried just wrapping the form in a div with an ngIf, to try and force it to re initialize. In this way, "cleaning" out the form from non existent fields so that validation does not bug out.